# How do you get text length in Swift 4?

Tags: uifont, swift4

I am not sure how to update this code:

```
func textWidth(text: String, font: UIFont?) -> CGFloat
{
    let attributes = font?.fontDescriptor.fontAttributes
    return text.size(withAttributes: attributes).width
}
```

Swift 4 complain: 
Cannot convert value of type '[UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName : Any]?' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]?'

I don't know why they broke this, but it does not get automatically fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**(SWIFT 4 Updated)**

```
func textWidth(text: String, font: UIFont?) -> CGFloat {
    let attributes = font != nil ? [NSFontAttributeName: font] : [:]
    return text.size(withAttributes: attributes).width
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, great minds think alike. That seems to be letter for letter the same as OOPer's solution of 27 June 17

I ended up using an extension of UIFont:
    public func textWidth(s: String) -> CGFloat
    {
        return s.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: self]).width
    }

Answer (score 5):

I guess, you want to write something like this:

(Swift 4)

```
func textWidth(text: String, font: UIFont?) -> CGFloat {
    let attributes = font != nil ? [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font!] : [:]
    return text.size(withAttributes: attributes).width
}
```

(Swift 3)

```
func textWidth(text: String, font: UIFont?) -> CGFloat {
    let attributes = font != nil ? [NSFontAttributeName: font!] : [:]
    return text.size(attributes: attributes).width
}
```

`fontAttributes` is not a valid input for `size(withAttributes:)` (`size(attributes:)` in Swift 3) even if the type matches.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to do this in Swift 4, avoiding the handling of the optional, is like this:

```
  extension UIFont { 


    func textWidth(s: String) -> CGFloat
    {
        return s.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: self]).width
    }

}
```

Comment: that return wrong size for me :( 
let font =  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        -> return CGSize(12 + font.textWidth(s: service.licenseName!), 50) -> wrong size, label does not show full text